# EF CF 4.2 and SQL Instead of insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency, triggers, ef-code-first

I have a CF class:

```
public class A
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int Id {get;set;}
  [Required]
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string LoweredName {get;set;}
  [Timestamp]
  public byte[] RowVersion {get;set;}
}
```

In the database i have a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IOI_LoweredName
   ON  Abc
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS; 
BEGIN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Abc(Name, LoweredName) SELECT Name, LOWER(Name) FROM inserted
END;
```

Now if i try to insert a record:

```
dc.Names.Add(new A { Name = "Test" });
dc.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Any ideas how to get around this?
All my classes inherit from a base class that has the RowVersion (Timestamp) column. Can't i use such a simple trigger with EF when using concurrency on a timestamp field ?

**Updated**

There is a primary key (also added it to the example above).

**Update 2**

This is from the SQL Profiler:

```
declare @0 nvarchar(100)
set @0=N'Test'
insert [dbo].[abc]([Name], [LoweredCompanyName]) values (@0, null)
select [Id], [RowVersion] from [dbo].[Abc] where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Problem is that the select doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do you actually get the error when you call SaveChanges or later on in the code?

Comment: When it tries to execute the SaveChanges().

Comment: Does your trigger actually not insert RowVersion or is it just a simplification?

Comment: I can't insert RowVersion since that is not supported in a trigger. RowVersion is of type timestamp. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx

Comment: Here is, at least, an explanation of the problem; http://blog.cincura.net/229478-instead-of-triggers-in-ms-sql-and-entity-framework-problem/

Comment: Think i will have to go with that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entity doesn't have primary key. EF will not like it.

To fix the current error try to add this at the end of your trigger:

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

If you change your code to support auto generated PK, you will use this instead:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I'm not sure if this will actually work with instead of trigger but it was necessary when mapping stored procedures to modification operations in EDMX.

Currently it is possible that this operation will be executed by EF directly but it will not count records created or modified by trigger because trigger executes in different scope - that can be a big problem.

Comment: I left that one out just for the simplicity of the class. It has a primary key. See above i updated the question.

Comment: So what happens if you try to select scope identity from the trigger?

Comment: Then i get this message "The member with identity '' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity"

Comment: Try `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY AS Id`

Comment: The solution in the end was to use a stored procedure since the trigger gets executed in a different scope. By creating a stored procedure i could use that to do the triggers role and that one only had to return the data expected by my POCO class to be used with CF.

Answer (score 1):

@ Patrick

Try this

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as [EXAMPLE]
```

Where [EXAMPLE] is the name of the identity column

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER IOI_LoweredName 
   ON  Abc 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS;  
BEGIN; 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    INSERT INTO Abc(Name, LoweredName)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id,INSERTED.RowVersion,
    SELECT Name, LOWER(Name) 
    FROM inserted 
END;
```